# When is binary tree better than ordered list?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, sortedlist

I understand differences between them, but I can't find any situation when binary tree is better. Searching, inserting and so cost more or less the same. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why is air better than water?

Comment: To search a list of 1024 items takes 1023 compares, to search a binary tree of 1024 items takes 9 compares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Searching** takes `O(n)` in an ordered (linked-)list (as you need to iterate through the entire linked-list to find the correct element), while it takes `O(log n)` in a (self-balancing) binary (search) tree (BST) (because, at each node, you can either look left or right, effectively splitting the input in roughly half).

While **insert and delete** can theoretically be performed in `O(1)` in a linked-list, you need to search for the correct position to insert or find the element to delete first, so these operations will also take `O(n)`, as opposed to a BST, where they take `O(log n)`.

**What's the difference between `O(n)` and `O(log n)`?**

Well, we can just substitute a value or two for `n` and see what we get. For `n = 1 000 000`, `log n = 19.93`. From this it's not too difficult to see that `log n` is *much* less than `n`. So, except for very small data sets, `O(log n)` is greatly preferred above `O(n)`.

**Technical notes:**

"list" might be ambiguous - it's mostly used to refer to a linked-list, but, in some cases, it's used to refer to an array. I assumed linked-list. For an array, the analysis is somewhat different, but we still get O(n) for insert and delete.

It needs to be a binary *search* tree, otherwise we're really comparing apples and oranges - a plain binary tree is an unordered data structure. The BST also needs to be self-balancing, otherwise you can get a very unbalanced tree (in the worst case, making it look like a linked-list), leading to `O(n)` operations.

I didn't mention **update** as it can just be implemented as a *delete* followed by an *insert*.

**So, is an ordered linked-list ever useful?**

It definitely is of limited use, but it does outperform a BST is some cases.

Consider if you mainly use the list as a queue or a stack (you mainly remove from or insert at the front or the back, which are `O(1)` operations, where-as these operations are `O(log n)` in a BST).

Comment: Hm, if I use binary search on ordered list it also makes O(logN). Same with insert/update/delete, doesn't it?

Comment: Show me binary search algorithm for ordered list.

Comment: @Hipolith "list" here is possibly a bit ambiguous - it's mostly used to refer to a linked-list, but, in some cases, it's used to refer to an array. That's why I put "(linked-)" in brackets. And if it's a linked-list, you can't do an (`O(log n)`) binary search on it, as you don't have **constant-time random access** (you take `O(n)` to get to an element by index). If you were talking about an array, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @bernhard-barker We are talking about an array. I say list too because that's what an array is called in Python. I think the answer is: You would begin the search by starting at the middle index, determining if your input is smaller or larger, then go to the left or right depending on that, and repeat, just like a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Balanced binary tree has Insert/Search/Update/Delete `O(logN)`, ordered list has Insert/Serach/Upade/Delete `O(N)`. The difference is matter of how big is your `N` compared to corresponding constants. So yes, you are wrong.

Comment: Hm, if I use binary search on ordered list it also makes O(logN). Same with insert/update/delete, doesn't it?

Comment: How will you do search in ordered list in O(logN)?

Comment: @hipolith You cant do a binary search on a linked list.

Comment: I agree with @Hipolith. You would begin the search by starting at the middle index, determining if your input is smaller or larger, then go to the left or right depending on that, and repeat, just like a tree. to richard: it's an ordered list, not necessarily implemented as a a linked list, but same rule probably applies (I don't really use linked lists)

Comment: @JoeFlack Tell me you don't know how linked lists (even double linked) work without telling me you don't know how linked lists work.

Comment: I'm just talking about an ordered array / list, like a python list, as I alluded to.